# We're graduating!

Tags: discussion

Retrocomputing Stack Exchange is leaving beta on the 16th of December. [Here's the official announcement.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/16/congratulations-are-in-order-these-sites-are-leaving-beta/)

### What is beta?

As the (somewhat out of date) [Help Center article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta) says:

> “Beta” means that the site is still being defined and constructed

We've done pretty well at this, I think.

- We've got a good understanding of what's on-topic and what's not.
- Most of our tags have detailed tag wiki excerpts, explaining how and why they should be used.
- Us [pro tem moderators](//stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/) are doing [less than half the work](/q/978/278).
- 96% of our questions are answered, with an average of 2.6 answers per question.
- We've got over 3000 visits per day. (3142, at time of writing.)

Apart from making an FAQ, and the (hotly debated) 10 questions per day metric, we meet [all the classic criteria for graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223675).

### What graduation means

There are several aspects to graduation. These used to be bundled together as an all-or-nothing thing, but they [aren't any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303727). This means:

- Losing the beta label (yes! 16th December 2021, give or take)

  - "Graduated" on our [Area 51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94441/retrocomputing)
  - Removing the “Site Stats” and “Help us grow this site!” boxes shown to anonymous users.
- Moderator elections (2022 or 2023)
- Migration paths, maybe, if we ask for them.

But we won't have:

- Increased reputation thresholds
- [Custom site design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/308065) (but we might get minor customisation)

### How we can prepare

If you think we shouldn't graduate, for whatever reason, please say so: there's still time to slam on the brakes.

Otherwise, we don't *really* need to do anything. If you want to, though, here are some ideas:

- Write tag wiki excerpts for every single tag. I think this is achievable, even for weird tags like [sd-card](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd-card), [military](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) and [tracker](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tracker).
- Approve (or reject) the [pending tag synonyms](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=Suggested)
- Make sure the /help/on-topic page is up to date. (You can edit it [here](/a/634/278).)
- Make an index for the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) questions and comment discussions, so it's easier for new users to look up whether something's on topic.
- Write some [faq-proposed](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) Q&A pairs, or edit existing questions into FAQs. (New-ish users: you're the best for this. If you have had a question about how the site works, chances are it's FAQ-worthy.)
- Answer some [unanswered questions](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/unanswered).
- Start thinking of [questions for our first moderator election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361).

  - Also consider who you might want to nominate, and whether you might want to nominate yourself.
- Visit [The BBS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38597/the-bbs), and give the [Annoying Robot](/q/597/278) some company. Maybe even have a party?

Comment: Yay!!!! Endlich.

Comment: At last! (....)

Comment: ‘We've got a good understanding of what's on-topic and what's not.’ — unless it’s an emulator question…

Comment: Also, ‘If you have had a question about how the site works’ — are we supposed to be building the main site FAQ or a Meta FAQ?

Comment: At the linked central Meta question it is mentioned in a few places that 10 questions per day threshold is still required to trigger moderator elections. Is this correct?

Comment: @user3840170 Why not both? Meta _is_ (almost) its own meta site, after all. Though, given how far we've got without one, an FAQ is probably not _necessary_.

Comment: @user3840170 And no, the 10 questions per day threshold won't be required for us. The official announcement when we actually graduate will explain things. (Moderator elections require a great deal of behind-the-scenes work, so they're _always_ triggered manually.)

Comment: What about ‘minor customisation’? I assume we can forget about something like ELU, but I wouldn’t like the site to keep looking as bland as Writing or Law…

Comment: @user3840170 They haven't implemented the code for that yet, but when they have, we'll get access to it. (Modulo them not having that many people to handle our requests.)

Comment: @user3840170 Which is essentially the design we have right now - sans the BETA tag that is. So I guess it should not be an issue to keep it that way. Seconded.

Comment: Champagne anyone?

Comment: @knol - only if it's properly aged; otherwise it's not really suited for this forum.

Comment: @another-dave If you re-used the bottle, would that qualify as [tag:old-hardware-adaptation]?

Comment: But somehow, I can still cast close votes on others’ questions with just over 1000 rep... Why aren’t rep thresholds raised?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE They haven't been linked for over five years. It's a multi-stage thing. (Shameless self-promotion: I made [a PPCG challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78316/43394) on the subject.)

Comment: FWIW - There was a discussion on building site logos a while back.  Might come in handy now! https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/is-there-a-logo-for-this-site/

Answer (score 2):

From the [central Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/):

> In the past, we were able to offer a custom site design to graduated sites. Although site redesigns aren’t happening right now, we have a shared interest internally in experimenting with ways to get this or similar benefits back. We know the sites that lost their “Beta” label in 2019 are still waiting for a redesign, too. We hope that some sort of design love (or perhaps theme customization) will come in the future, but we don't have concrete details of what this will look like or a timeline of when this will happen.

Since we are apparently not getting a custom theme any time soon, I decided to celebrate by creating a tiny user style sheet to customise the header.

```
.site-header {
    font-family: 'Pet Me 64', 'C64 Pro', monospace;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    --theme-header-link-color: #5090d0;
    --theme-header-background-color: #181090;
}

.site-header .site-header--link {
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.site-header .site-header--link::after {
    content: '█';
}
```

For Meta:

```
.site-header {
    --theme-header-link-color: silver;
    --theme-header-background-color: black;
}
```

Install it with [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/).  You will have to also install the fonts [Pet Me](https://www.kreativekorp.com/software/fonts/c64.shtml) or [C64 Pro](https://style64.org/c64-truetype) yourself, as I have nowhere to point a `@font-face` declaration to.

Not much of a change, actually, and not a design I put too much thought to.  It’s just something quick-and-dirty to make the site look a little less bland.  I had some other ideas, but I decided not to spend the effort on them just yet.

Comment: I made the prompt blink with `animation: blink-box 2s infinite;` after `content: '█';`, and `@keyframes blink-box {
  50% { content: ' '; }
}` at the end. (This is probably too annoying for the actual site, but I think it's neat.)

Comment: I thought about it too, then decided it’s too annoying indeed and left it out.