# Congratulations Retrocomputing!

Tags: discussion

I noticed this morning that Retrocomputing is finally out of Beta!  Congratulations.  It's possible that I'm late to the party and just didn't notice until now.  When was this stack promoted?

Answer (score 6):

On the 16th of December: [We're graduating!](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/were-graduating) (Official post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/16/congratulations-are-in-order-these-sites-are-leaving-beta/).

Comment: Heh.  It would appear my alertness factor is a bit under 9000.  Thanks for link.

Comment: Also relevant.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/236563