# Should we add a favicon to the main site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Our site favicon (the websites little tab icon aka [image: favicon (meta)] for meta and [image: favicon (meta)] for regular) is pretty plain right now. The banner is also a bit stereotypical.

Should we change the banner and favicon to add difference and theme to the site more towards Retrocomputing, and less towards your everyday vanilla StackExchange site?

We could do a mini pixelated computer for the favicon or something. I'm sure you moderators will be able to come up with good ideas :)

For those who want some more info on this, we have tried to get a logo [once](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/is-there-a-logo-for-this-site/), but this was [before graduating](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/were-graduating). I think soon we should switch our logo to something more retrocomputery (if that is even a word ;) ). I have absolutely no idea how to do this but I think we can do it.

Comment: This is normally something that just _happens_; Stack Exchange's designers have a backlog they're working through, and we're rather a way down the list. But if there's enough community support, I'll raise this higher up, just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We as a group can't change our favicon.  The SE designers create a theme for graduated sites which includes a favicon amongst several other features.

When they get around to us, we'll get something on this meta site asking for views.  Compare with other sites that have recently graduated...

[Motor Vehicle Maintenance](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2127/6299)
[Ethereum](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/706/110)
[Gardening and Landscaping](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/961/20139)

..to name but three.

A lot of sites graduated in a short space of time a few months ago.  at the moment we just have to be patient.

But you can see from those other sites the sort of things we can affect.  Be prepared with ideas for when the call comes.

Related to this is a post on the main meta...
[How long until graduated sites get a new site design and increased privileges threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290363/236563)
... which indicates that some sites that graduated in 2019 still don't have a themed design.

Comment: Oh, great.  Now we'll be arguing about whether we want a picture of an N64 or a CDC 6600  :-)